# Are there any relationships between the given name Pompeius and the city name Pompeii?

Tags: names, place-names

Are there any relationships between the given name Pompeius (like in Gnaeus Pompeius Magnus) and the city name Pompeii (the city thas was destroyed in a volcanic eruption? What do they mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Pompeius* probably comes from the Oscan praenomen *Pompo*, which is the equivalent of the Latin *Quintus*, as its root is *pompe* - traceable to the Greek *pente*, i.e. "five".

The name of the city *might* have the same origin - quoting the [English Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pompeii), this could suggest that either the community consisted of five hamlets or, perhaps, it was settled by the gens Pompeia.

On the other hand the *Parco Archeologico di Pompei* gave in a [Facebook post](https://www.facebook.com/pompeiisoprintendenza/photos/a.1523717371268809/1778386109135266/?type=3&theater) three possibilities. "All of them are potentially believable", but the origin from *pompe* is indeed said to be the most accredited hypothesis - the gens Pompeia was not mentioned though. Here are the other two possibilities:

- According to the geographer Strabo of 60 BC, it might derive from the greek *pempo* ("to sent"), for its proximity to the Sarno River where goods arrived and departed.
- Maurus Servius Honoratus speculated in the 4th century that the toponym could be traced back to a hypothetical foundation by Hercules, *a pompa Herculis* ("from Hercules' triumph") which would then become *Pompeii* in time.